# C# azure table query returning 501 not implemented

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm using Azure Table Storage and have a table I am trying to query where the row key ends with some value I am interested in filtering by. Here is my code:

```
var query = table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(o => o.PartitionKey == somePartitionKey && o.RowKey.EndsWith(string.Format("_{0}", aclId))).AsTableQuery();
```

I then perform a `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` but for some reason that throws the following exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.

Any ideas why this is? Do I have a problem with my code/query causing it to fail? At any rate I really need an efficient way to retrieve all the records in a partition where the row key ends with some value.

Comment: What nuget package and version are you using for Azure Storage?

Comment: Is your storage account created in Classic or Resource Manager mode?

Comment: I see that you're using endswith in your query. Please note that endswith operator is not supported with Azure tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to perform an unsupported operation. As of today, Azure Table Service doesn't support `EndsWith` query operator. For the list of supported LINQ operators, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135725.aspx.

In your scenario, you will need to download the entities on the client side first and then apply `EndsWith` operator on those entities.

Comment: Perfect link, thanks! I am disappointed with Azure. Between not supporting such queries - including even simple aggregates such as a count of all entities in a partition - it seems they are really limiting performance/efficiency. At times I question the purpose behind having a data storage mechanism that is cheap and "fast" if you're not even really able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember Blob storage does not have access to table services only general purpose ones. So if you run into this and you know that you have setup a blob storage resource then it's not going to work.